# duration between 2 states

Tags: flutter, datetime

I am building an app in which whenever the widget state changes I want to set a background timer so when the state changes again I can get the last widget state time (i.e. duration between 2 states).

Answer (score 1):

Every time the state changes, you can create a lastModified timestamp. When the state changes the next time, you find the difference between now and lastModified, store that interval, and then change lastModified to now. Snippet below.

State Change Timer Demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'State Change Timer',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _lastModified = DateTime.now();
  Duration _interval = const Duration(seconds: 0);

  void _changeState() {
    setState(() {
      _interval = DateTime.now().difference(_lastModified);
      _lastModified = DateTime.now();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("State Change Timer"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Last State Change Interval',
            ),
            Text(
              _interval.inSeconds.toString() + " seconds",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _changeState,
        tooltip: 'Change State',
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```